Reactjs popdown menus using material ui for desktop and mobile modes
I want to create a menu navigation similar to the UX/design here.
Desktop

Mobile

This is as far as I have got - but there is an issue opening up the popup menus - I am not sure what is stopping this from working -- I think the boolean if its open or not is always false -- and its as if the ancor is always wrong or not handled correctly -if its because its stashing an array item - and maybe it should be considered just 1 menu - as only 1 menu will be open at anyone time? What is the fix for this and the best architecture - for also setting up and getting mobile menu displaying in a responsive build?
I broke it up into topnav and submenu -- but now the menu opens - but it doesnt map/ancor to the correct menu or any menu - as if the ancor is null?
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wizardly-poitras-forked-srvmxt
SubMenu
import React from "react";
import { Menu, MenuItem } from "@mui/material";

const SubMenu = ({ anchorEl, open, submenu, onMenuClose, onMenuItemClick }) => {
  return (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={anchorEl} // Position the menu relative to the button
      open={open} // Open/close based on state
      onClose={onMenuClose} // Close when clicked outside
      MenuListProps={{
        "aria-labelledby": "submenu",
      }}
      anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: "bottom", // Menu opens below the button
        horizontal: "right", // Menu opens to the right of the button
      }}
      transformOrigin={{
        vertical: "top", // Align the top of the menu with the button
        horizontal: "right", // Align the right side of the menu with the button
      }}
    >
      {submenu.map((submenuItem) => (
        <MenuItem
          key={submenuItem.action}
          onClick={() => onMenuItemClick(submenuItem.action)}
        >
          {submenuItem.label}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Menu>
  );
};

export default SubMenu;

TopNav
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Button, Typography, Avatar } from "@mui/material";
import PersonSearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PersonSearch"; // Icon for "For recruiters"
import WorkIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Work"; // Icon for "My career"
import FavoriteBorderIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorder"; // Icon for "My jobs"
import AccountCircleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle"; // Icon for "Billy"
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore"; // Chevron down for open
import ChevronRightIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ChevronRight"; // Chevron right for closed

import SubMenu from "./SubMenu"; // Import SubMenu component

// Menu data with explicit keys
const menuData = [
  {
    key: "forRecruiters",
    label: "For recruiters",
    icon: PersonSearchIcon,
    submenu: null,
  },
  {
    key: "myCareer",
    label: "My career",
    icon: WorkIcon,
    submenu: [
      { label: "Career Overview", action: "career-overview" },
      { label: "Manage Profile", action: "manage-profile" },
      { label: "Settings", action: "career-settings" },
    ],
  },
  {
    key: "myJobs",
    label: "My jobs",
    icon: FavoriteBorderIcon,
    submenu: [
      { label: "Job Listings", action: "job-listings" },
      { label: "Saved Jobs", action: "saved-jobs" },
      { label: "Applied Jobs", action: "applied-jobs" },
    ],
  },
  {
    key: "loggedUser", // Updated key for "Billy"
    label: "Billy",
    icon: AccountCircleIcon,
    avatarImage:
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Brad_Pitt_2019.jpg", // Billy's avatar
    submenu: [
      { label: "Profile", action: "billy-profile" },
      { label: "Notifications", action: "billy-notifications" },
      { label: "Settings", action: "billy-settings" },
    ],
  },
];

class TopNav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      anchorEls: {}, // To store the anchor element for each menu
      openMenus: {}, // To track which menu is open
    };
  }

  // Handle opening a menu and closing others
  handleMenuOpen = (event, key) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const newOpenMenus = { ...prevState.openMenus };
      const isCurrentlyOpen = newOpenMenus[key];

      // Close all menus
      Object.keys(newOpenMenus).forEach((menu) => {
        newOpenMenus[menu] = false;
      });

      // Toggle the clicked menu
      newOpenMenus[key] = !isCurrentlyOpen;

      return {
        anchorEls: { ...prevState.anchorEls, [key]: event.currentTarget }, // Set the anchorEl for the clicked menu
        openMenus: newOpenMenus,
      };
    });
  };

  // Handle closing a menu
  handleMenuClose = (key) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      anchorEls: { ...prevState.anchorEls, [key]: null },
      openMenus: { ...prevState.openMenus, [key]: false },
    }));
  };

  // Handle click on a menu item
  handleMenuItemClick = (action, key) => {
    console.log(`Clicked on action: ${action}`);
    this.handleMenuClose(key); // Close the menu after action
  };

  render() {
    const { anchorEls, openMenus } = this.state;

    return (
      <AppBar position="sticky">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            MyApp
          </Typography>

          {/* Loop over menu items */}
          {menuData.map((item) => {
            const { key, label, icon: Icon, avatarImage, submenu } = item;

            return (
              <React.Fragment key={key}>
                <Button
                  color="inherit"
                  onClick={(event) =>
                    submenu ? this.handleMenuOpen(event, key) : null
                  }
                  startIcon={label === "Billy" ? null : <Icon />}
                  endIcon={
                    submenu ? (
                      openMenus[key] ? (
                        <ExpandMoreIcon />
                      ) : (
                        <ChevronRightIcon />
                      )
                    ) : null
                  }
                  sx={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}
                >
                  {/* Display Avatar if this is the loggedUser ("Billy") menu item */}
                  {avatarImage && label === "Billy" && (
                    <Avatar
                      alt={label}
                      src={avatarImage}
                      sx={{ width: 32, height: 32, marginRight: 1 }}
                    />
                  )}
                  {label}
                </Button>

                {/* Show submenus if available and menu is open */}
                {submenu && openMenus[key] && (
                  <SubMenu
                    anchorEl={anchorEls[key]} // Position the menu relative to the button
                    open={openMenus[key]} // Open based on the openMenus state
                    submenu={submenu} // Pass the submenu items
                    onMenuClose={() => this.handleMenuClose(key)} // Close menu when clicked outside
                    onMenuItemClick={(action) =>
                      this.handleMenuItemClick(action, key)
                    } // Handle item click
                  />
                )}
              </React.Fragment>
            );
          })}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    );
  }
}

export default TopNav;

